# Notification bar doesn't work anymore

Tags: notification-bar

I have stock (rooted) android on my acer lcona B1 A71. 
My notification bar is empty since I had to do hardware reset my machine by pin pressing with toothpick above the power button.

I can't for example receive any file via bloototh - confrmation is required but there is nothing since my notification bar is 'frozen'.
There are some things that still work: input selection when keyboard is active and wifi network name is allways correct.
What's interesting i can toggle rotate/lock screen orientation but can't get into settings by pressing icon next to it.

Have you got any clues what may be the cause? 
Which process is responsible for notifications? Maybe I can clean some corrupted cache files or something?

I'm tech guy but not from android-world. 
I can invoke some shell commands to give you more data etc...

Maybe there is some related thread on xda forum or answered question here that I've missed.
Just point me to it if you know there is.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe your digitizer is getting damaged.

Comment: It might be the digitizer, as roxan suggested. But if it worked fine until the reset, and started broken immediately following the reset, it could well be a software issue. You could try clearing all cache (using e.g. [Clean Master](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Clean-Master/com.cleanmaster.mguard) – though I doubt this will help). Or you might rather try a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) (make a backup before!), which would also clear the Dalvik cache. If the latter doesn't solve it, it's a hardware issue and a case for the service team.

Comment: Digitizer - do you mean touch screen not working in particullar area? No no, this is not the thing for sure. This is *not* "can't slide notif-bar" issue. It's about the notification system itself. Notification drawer area stays empty all the time, I can open and close it without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue one week ago. Today I flashed an AOKP ROM using cwm and finally everything runs well.